# Slack API - persistent message visible only to a set of users in a public channel

Tags: slack, slack-api

I'm planning to write a slack app, and I need to render messages depending on who read them.

I'm thinking something like: the App should have some options, and user's clients should render the messages depending on the options chosen by the user.

**Is there a way to post a persistent message (I mean not an ephemeral message) which is shown only to a user (or a set of users)?**

Or

**Is it possible to post a message shown differently depending on the user who read it?**

I don't need to send *private* or *sensitive* data, so if the solution to my problem is a message containing all the content for all the users in the channel, it is perfectly fine. It's just matter of user experience.

I have two constraints:

1. The user experience for those who don't use the App should not be impacted
2. I need the messages from the App to be rendered in reply to messages sent by the users, so solutions like "open a new channel" or "send direct messages" are not suitable for my needs.

Thank you all (but the Slack team which, in case let us doing that, it makes that not clear in the documentation :D )

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible unless you create your own client to show/display the messages.

Custom slack apps usually augment to the existing functionality. 
How do you expect to **override** the functionality of Native Slack 'Desktop, Mobile & Web' Client.

I am happy to discuss this further, if you have some approach in mind.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately it is the answer I was afraid to expect. Writing a new client is absolutely out of budget, that would mean not only to write it but to keep it updated with new features added from Slack as well. I was thinking something like a new property in the message blocks with an array of userId to show it, but that would require a change from Slack both on API side (checking blocks syntax) and on client side (to honor the new property). I asked this to Slack some months ago, but I neither received an answer. :(

Comment: Another option could be a client side addon/plugin, but AFAIK the Slack client can't be modded.

Comment: I agree to both of your comments.